# How to skip to a particular option in man pages?

Tags: command-line, manpage

I have a simple request: Is there a way to quickly find out what a particular option for a command means using `man`? I know you can just Google for it, but I want to use the man pages if possible.

Something like `man ls -l` which seems identical to be identical to `man ls`, but I would like to find out what the `-l` option does, without having to scroll down to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can search a man page using `\{pattern}`.

So in your example, do `man ls` then while in the man page `\-l` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This will highlight all instances of `-l`.

You can toggle the highlight with <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>.

Pressing <kbd>n</kbd> moves the cursor to the next occurrence. Pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> moves the cursor to the previous occurrence.